# ToC recognise that List of Figures has two pages

Tags: table-of-contents, lists

I have the problem that my List of Figures and List of Tables is each two pages long. In the ToC, they are counted with one page so that subsequent page numbers are wrong. How can I fix the ToC to account for the length of the List of Tables/Figures?

```
\normalsize
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\clearpage

\pagenumbering{roman}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}
\section*{Abstract}

{r child = '0_3_Abstract.Rmd'}

\clearpage

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.75}\normalsize
\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}\normalsize


\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}
\listoftables
\clearpage
```

Produces: [image: ToC], where the List of Tables actually starts on page v and not iv.

Comment: try to replace `\clearpage` and `\newpage` with `\cleardoublepage`

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Have you compiled the file more than once after these two lists are complete?  Adding page numbers is a two-cycle process.